# What is the most efficient way to merge objects with nested and date keys?

Tags: javascript, arrays, ecmascript-6, javascript-objects

This is an example dataset:

```
const largeObject = {  
"4249":{  
  "2018-07-25":[  
     {  
        "start":"2016-07-25T14:09:20.453Z",
        "end":"2016-07-25T14:17:52.147Z"
     }
  ]
},
"9939":{  
  "2018-07-25":[  
     {  
        "start":"2016-07-25T00:50:08.768Z",
        "end":"2016-07-25T00:53:16.514Z"
     }
  ]
},
"2149":{  
  "2018-07-25":[  
     {  
        "start":"2016-07-25T00:42:02.569Z",
        "end":"2016-07-25T00:43:07.689Z"
     }
  ]
},
"6929":{  
  "2018-07-24":[  
     {  
        "start":"2016-07-24T00:44:30.479Z",
        "end":"2016-07-24T00:46:41.315Z"
     }
  ]
},
"7930":{  
  "2018-07-24":[  
     {  
        "start":"2016-07-24T00:39:44.152Z",
        "end":"2016-07-24T00:44:05.420Z"
     }
  ]
},
"4796":{  
  "2018-07-22":[  
     {  
        "start":"2016-07-22T12:48:56.169Z",
        "end":"2016-07-22T13:38:28.136Z"
     }
  ]
}
}
```

I am trying to find the most efficient way to get to something like this:

```
   const filteredObject = {
 "2018-07-25": [         
     {  
        "start":"2016-07-25T14:09:20.453Z",
        "end":"2016-07-25T14:17:52.147Z"
     },          {  
        "start":"2016-07-25T00:50:08.768Z",
        "end":"2016-07-25T00:53:16.514Z"
     },
     {  
        "start":"2016-07-25T00:42:02.569Z",
        "end":"2016-07-25T00:43:07.689Z"
     }
   ],
"2018-07-24": [         
    {  
        "start":"2016-07-24T00:44:30.479Z",
        "end":"2016-07-24T00:46:41.315Z"
    },
    {  
        "start":"2016-07-24T00:39:44.152Z",
        "end":"2016-07-24T00:44:05.420Z"
    }
  ],
"2018-07-22": [  
     {  
        "start":"2016-07-22T12:48:56.169Z",
        "end":"2016-07-22T13:38:28.136Z"
     }
]    
};
```

So far, I have done:

```
const filteredObject = {}
const newArr = []
for(key in largeObject){
  console.log(largeObject[key])  
}
```

And that gets rid of the random string, but still gets me this:

```
{ '2018-07-24': 
[ { start: '2016-07-24T00:44:30.479Z',
    end: '2016-07-24T00:46:41.315Z' } ] }
{ '2018-07-25': 
  [ { start: '2016-07-25T00:50:08.768Z',
      end: '2016-07-25T00:53:16.514Z' } ] }
{ '2018-07-25': 
  [ { start: '2016-07-25T14:09:20.453Z',
      end: '2016-07-25T14:17:52.147Z' } ] }
  { '2018-07-24': 
  [ { start: '2016-07-24T00:39:44.152Z',
      end: '2016-07-24T00:44:05.420Z' } ] }
{ '2018-07-22': 
  [ { start: '2016-07-22T12:48:56.169Z',
      end: '2016-07-22T13:38:28.136Z' } ] }
{ '2018-07-25': 
  [ { start: '2016-07-25T00:42:02.569Z',
      end: '2016-07-25T00:43:07.689Z' } ] }
```

This is far as I've gotten. I still need to find a way to merge all the arrays with the same key values. It seems like I would need to iterate over this object, keep the date as the key, and push all of the arrays associated with that date-key into one array.

What would be the best way to handle something like this? I also want to do this as efficient as possible without having to iterate over the entire large object each time I check for the date-key and/or push the start/end object into an array of it's own.

Comment: Have you made any attempt so far yourself? Please post the code you've tried

Comment: Well, I tried to console.log two nested for in loops and push the values of the second loop into another array. For example:

for(key in largeObject){
  for(theDate in key) {
    console.log("theDate: ", theDate)
  }
}

But that prints only the characters per string

Comment: `I tried to console.log` - console.log doesn't actually do anything, it's used to debug code - of which you seem to have written zero lines

Comment: I was only mentioning console.log so as to let readers know where I was in my thought process. It's unfair to assume I haven't written any code, especially since I have since updated my question...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can start with `Object.values()` of your original data. This will give you an array of the values without the first level keys over which you can [`reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce). Then for each of those break it into a key and value. Add the key with an array value if it's not already there and merge in the data.

```js
const largeObject = {  "4249":{  "2018-07-25":[  {  "start":"2016-07-25T14:09:20.453Z","end":"2016-07-25T14:17:52.147Z"}]},"9939":{  "2018-07-25":[  {  "start":"2016-07-25T00:50:08.768Z","end":"2016-07-25T00:53:16.514Z"}]},"2149":{  "2018-07-25":[  {  "start":"2016-07-25T00:42:02.569Z","end":"2016-07-25T00:43:07.689Z"}]},"6929":{  "2018-07-24":[  {  "start":"2016-07-24T00:44:30.479Z","end":"2016-07-24T00:46:41.315Z"}]},"7930":{  "2018-07-24":[  {  "start":"2016-07-24T00:39:44.152Z","end":"2016-07-24T00:44:05.420Z"}]},"4796":{  "2018-07-22":[  {  "start":"2016-07-22T12:48:56.169Z","end":"2016-07-22T13:38:28.136Z"}]}}
    
let filtered = Object.values(largeObject).reduce((a, c) => {
    Object.entries(c).forEach(([k, v]) => {
        (a[k] || (a[k] = [])).push(...v)
    })
    return a
},{})
console.log(filtered)
```